# SQL, Add a time field in a date column

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g, sqldatatypes

I have a field that gives me time and it is expressed like this :

7:00 AM

the problem is that when i try to add it to the column that should contain time it gives me error because the format is wrong.

I tried to change the format using to_char but it is giving me an error saying that the function is not implemented.

here is the code.

```
CREATE TABLE call_info
(
    call_id NUMBER(4) 
    CONSTRAINT cio_call_id_CK CHECK (call_id >= 1000 AND call_id <= 9999),
    report_first VARCHAR2(10),
    report_last VARCHAR2(11) CONSTRAINT cio_report_last_NN NOT NULL,
    report_date DATE CONSTRAINT cio_report_date_NN NOT NULL,
    report_time DATE CONSTRAINT cio_report_time_NN NOT NULL,
    problem_code NUMBER(1) CONSTRAINT cio_problem_code_NN NOT NULL,
    service_code VARCHAR2(4),
    CONSTRAINT cio_call_id_PK PRIMARY KEY (call_id),
    CONSTRAINT cio_problem_code_FK FOREIGN KEY (problem_code) 
    REFERENCES problems(code),
    CONSTRAINT cio_service_code_FK FOREIGN KEY (service_code)
    REFERENCES services(code)   
)
;

BEGIN 
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1102','Bill','Madden',TO_DATE('29-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('7:00 PM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'2','PSEG');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1103','Anita','Verno',TO_DATE('29-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('7:01 PM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'2','PSEG');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1200','Emily','Vandalovsky',TO_DATE('29-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('7:45 PM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'2','PSEG');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1111','Gary','Correa',TO_DATE('29-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('8:10 PM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'1','DPR');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1101','Mickey','Mouse',TO_DATE('29-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('11:00 PM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'6','PSEG');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1012','Minnie','Mouse',TO_DATE('29-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('11:21 PM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'1','DPR');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1013','Goofy','Disney',TO_DATE('29-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('11:47 PM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'5','OEM');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1040','Donald','Duck',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2:34 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'4','OEM');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1501','Cinderella','Disney',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('3:15 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'3','CSH');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1506','Ernie','Sesame',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('3:16 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'3','CSH');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1007','Burt','Sesame',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('3:18 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'3','CSH');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1081','Bruce','Springsteen',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('4:10 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'2','PSEG');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1910','Chris','Christie',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('4:25 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'7','OEM');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1010','Mitt','Romney',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('5:15 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'1','DPR');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1015','Barack','Obama',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('5:17 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'1','DPR');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1019','Bruce','Wayne',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('7:57 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'5','OEM');
INSERT INTO call_info
VALUES ('1314','Minas','Kousoulis',TO_DATE('30-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('8:01 AM','hh:mi AM'),'hh:mi-AM'),'4','WTR');
END;
```

Please note this the date datatype cannot be changed to a different one.

Thank you for the attention.

Danilo

Comment: What are you storing a time in a separate field?  You should be putting the two in one column.

Comment: it is mandatory for the assignment to actually put them in separate columns. I wish it was in the same, it would have made my life way easier.

Comment: You should put them in one column anyway. You can split date and time for example by virtual column or with a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you storing the time in a separate field?  Are you aware that `DATE` has a "time" component?  Separating the fields almost never makes sense:

```
CREATE TABLE call_info (
    call_id NUMBER(4) 
    CONSTRAINT cio_call_id_CK CHECK (call_id >= 1000 AND call_id <= 9999),
    report_first VARCHAR2(10),
    report_last VARCHAR2(11) CONSTRAINT cio_report_last_NN NOT NULL,
    report_datetime DATE CONSTRAINT cio_report_date_NN NOT NULL,
    problem_code NUMBER(1) CONSTRAINT cio_problem_code_NN NOT NULL,
    service_code VARCHAR2(4),
    CONSTRAINT cio_call_id_PK PRIMARY KEY (call_id),
    CONSTRAINT cio_problem_code_FK FOREIGN KEY (problem_code) 
    REFERENCES problems(code),
    CONSTRAINT cio_service_code_FK FOREIGN KEY (service_code)
    REFERENCES services(code)   
);
```

Then I would suggest inserting values using Oracles `TIMESTAMP` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO call_info (call_id, report_first, report_last, report_datetime, problem_code, service_code)
    VALUES (1102, 'Bill', 'Madden', TIMETAMP '2017-10-29 19:00:00', 
2, 'PSEG');
```

Note that I also removed the single quotes around the numbers and the `insert` lists all the columns.

Comment: I understand, in this case i guess to satisfy the request of having two columns (it was specified in the demands for the exercise) i could always duplicate date and time (create 2 columns one with only date and another one with both date and time)  and then when calling the two column with the select statement i just get a partial part of the record. 
I think this could make it.